# bootstrap : unable/disable <a> link bootstrap using javascript

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

this is an active link

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-large">Link</a>
```

how to disable this link using javascript, so the code would be like this?

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-large disabled">Link</a>
```

Comment: In response to what you want it to be disabled?

Comment: to prevent the savechanges button clicked when data values not yet edited

Comment: Might be a duplicate of the question [What is the easiest way to disable/enable buttons and links (jQuery + Bootstrap)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16777003/4043409), asked two months before this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="myLink" class="btn btn-large">Link</a>
```

Pure JS

```
var d = document.getElementById("myLink");
d.className = d.className + " disabled";
```

jQuery

```
$('#myLink').addClass('disabled');
```

Comment: Notice that with this the button will just appear disabled but will still be clickable. To also make it unclickable, you can add this (jQuery): `$('#myLink').on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: In modern browsers and modern bootstrap, this code will not necessary because the `.btn:disabled` has `pointer-events:none` so it will not be clickable.

Answer (score -2):

Use the attribute `disabled` in a class, like `class="btn btn-danger disabled"`

For example:

`<a href="exampleLink.php?id=3&amp;option=1" class="btn btn-danger disabled" role="button">Cancelar</a>`