# How to enable and disable Twitter Bootstrap Button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button

I am trying to achieve the scenario of disabling a button on clicking it, and then enabling it again after the ajax request has completed successfully.

The below is the snippet of my code.

**Form**

```
<button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Submit!</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#resForm').validate({
  // disable submit button
  $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', true);

  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $.ajax({
      ..... typical ajax stuff .....
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        $('success').html(data);
        // enable reserve button again
        $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // console.log(jqXHR);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

It doesn't work. And checking my console on Chrome tells me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`. It feels like it's a stupid mistake somewhere and I can't figure it out. I have read that `prop` is meant for jQuery 1.6.1 and later and I am on 1.8.3.

Comment: Does the error specifies any line?Just try to run in firefox with the help of firebug..it will show you the exact problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('#resForm').validate({


  submitHandler: function(form) {
// disable submit button
  $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
    $.ajax({
      ..... typical ajax stuff .....
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        $('success').html(data);
        // enable reserve button again
        $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // console.log(jqXHR);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Try this

Comment: see .validate() api it has a definite structure...
u cannot add .prop in there...

Answer (score 2):

[From my answer to another post in SO!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777003/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-disable-enable-buttons-and-links-jquery-bootstrap/#answer-17935158) 
I can't think a simpler/easier way! ;-)

---

For Anchor Tags(Links) :

```
<a href="#delete-modal" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete"> Delete</a>
```

---

To enable the Anchor tag:

```
 $('#delete').removeClass('disabled');
 $('#delete').attr("data-toggle", "modal");
```

[image]

---

To disable the Anchor tag:

```
 $('#delete').addClass('disabled');
 $('#delete').removeAttr('data-toggle');
```

[image]

Comment: Hello. I don't quiet understand where to put this code which begins with $. Seriously, I am new to this stuff, can you point me to some resource or just a key words for me to search ? many thanks!

Comment: Inside a js function where you have your desired conditions! 
Check the if...else statement in Javascript!

Answer (score 0):

Use http://jsfiddle.net/ to check your code.

Try:

```
$('#resForm').validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
// disable submit button
  $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
    $.ajax({
      //..... typical ajax stuff .....
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        $('success').html(data);
        // enable reserve button again
        $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // console.log(jqXHR);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Fiddle with Correction: http://jsfiddle.net/shree/qB9aW/ .JSHint gives you a hint for error.