# How to Disable the button in kendo

Tags: jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

This is my Code sample

```
<button id="action-save" class="button-primary">Save Details</button>
```

how to disable this button?

I tried like value = "disabled" it doesn't worked out well

Comment: We need more details to help you

Comment: am trying to disable the button event but it is firing

Comment: Use HTML property disabled="disabled"

Comment: can you show the code you have already used?

Comment: @SamDenton I want to disable the property itself

Comment: then use disabled="disabled"

Comment: Guys why downvoting for question is there anything wrong?

Comment: you provided no code to show what you have tried, only what you want

Comment: glad i could help, but the answers bellow should get the credit, i just quoted from them

Comment: @SamDenton Thats my requirement actually i tried all those stuffs like value = "disabled" but it didn't work out

Comment: @SamDenton see i edited my question but still downvote i don't get it

Comment: downvotes dont just disapear when u edit

Comment: @SamDenton i know but it was -4 before after edit it went to -5

Comment: i cant help you, it is probaly just because some people like to downvote questions that other people have downvoted, just to be part of the croud

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to disable/enable buttons and links (jQuery + Bootstrap)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777003/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-disable-enable-buttons-and-links-jquery-bootstrap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HTML property:

```
disabled="disabled"
```

or just

```
disabled
```

So your HTML tag would look like this:

```
<button id="action-save" class="button-primary" disabled="disabled">Save Details</button>
```

or

```
<button id="action-save" class="button-primary" disabled>Save Details</button>
```

This will make the element unclickable/unselectable.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: You don't need to do `disabled="disabled"`. You can just type `disabled`.

Comment: @BeatAlex I have had some browser issues when using just disabled. But that was quite some time ago. So I always prefer to use disabled="disabled". Ah, but that could have just become my habit now. SO I've edited my answer to include both the ways.

Comment: Sweet, I've +1'd you too :)

Answer (score 2):

Just add  `disabled`?

```
<button id="action-save" class="button-primary" disabled>Save Details</button>
```

Comment: its a real pain when people dont give a reason for downvoting

Comment: I've upvoted it as it's right. No idea why it was downvoted. `disabled='disabled'` is only necessary in `xhtml`, which this is not. So `disabled` alone is fine.