# Data-bind click is not working in Chrome with nested for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, knockout.js

The below code works fine in IE. We have a download link which is getting disabled based on a condition. The same code is not working in Chrome.

In Chrome the Link is not getting disabled. Is there an alternative solution for this such that works in Chrome as well?

I have observed in the developer tools

In IE:

```html
<a disabled="" href="#" ...>
```

In Chrome:

```html
<a href="#"...>
```

**The `data-bind="click: $root.studentsp` where the `$root` which is not working in Chrome.**

We have used a nested loop in the code, this is the relevant Code Block:

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: studentDetails">
    <div class="row" id="Items">
        <table class="table table-striped branded-table" style="margin-top: 24px">
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: cp">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: rollno"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Format"></td>
                    <td> 
                         <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.studentsp, enable: !$root.isavailable()">displayed</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: isaviable? Do you mean isavailable?

Comment: jsFiddle example would help better

Comment: Can you show us your script?¿

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. The title claims "click event doesn't fire", but [the `click` is handled just fine in Chrome.](http://jsfiddle.net/q8rpenrt/1/). Your question says "the data-bind=click is not gettingdisabled": I'm not sure what that means, but it seems to be something different. Please realise that [the `enable` binding](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/enableDisable.js) will merely set the `disabled` attribute, which will not do much by default. Please edit your question and include a full repro for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs for the `enable` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/enable-binding.html), emphasis mine:

> The enable binding causes the associated DOM element to be enabled only when the parameter value is true. **This is useful with form elements like `input`, `select`, and `textarea`.**

You can also see this in [the relevant source file](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/enableDisable.js).

[There is no `disabled` attribute for anchor tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13955695/419956). The best source for alternatives is probably [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16777003/419956). Skipping that, going to a dumb but straightforward way to do it with just KnockoutJS would be:

```html
<a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.studentsp, visible: !$root.isavailable()">displayed</a>
<span data-bind="visible: !!$root.isavailable()">displayed</span>
```

---

Since OP's commented that this won't work as it would be "making the control invisible", here's a proof of concept for this solution:

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  studentsp: function() { alert('clicked'); },
  isavailable: ko.observable(false)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.studentsp, visible: !$root.isavailable()">displayed</a>
<span data-bind="visible: !!$root.isavailable()">displayed</span>
<hr />
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.isavailable" /> isavailable
```

Comment: Checked with this but completely making the control invisible.

Comment: Which is why I've explained in my comment to your question as well as my answer that it's important you *include an actual repro* for your situation in the question. As you can see from my edit, the basic solution I've posted works just fine.