# Avoid extending jQuery if not necessary

Tags: jquery, performance

I saw this post 
[What is the easiest way to disable/enable buttons and links (jQuery + Bootstrap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777003/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-disable-enable-buttons-and-links-jquery-bootstrap)

And I really like this:

```
// Disable function
jQuery.fn.extend({
    disable: function (state) {
        return this.each(function () {
            this.disabled = state;
        });
    }

});
```

My question is how would I avoid extending `$` (or a custom namespace for that matter)
See for ref also:
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

I'm looking for safety checks when using `extend` when it's not needed because obj has already been extended, this to improve performance.

Comment: You are right about avoiding to extend if not necessary.
Something simple like this, I'd just create a function for it. 

Whatever design pattern you use, you can easily make it re-usable anyway.

However back to your question: you'd have to extend the extend function ;) I'm not sure if that's possible out of the box at all.

Comment: If you're using [browsers which support it](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Object_static_methods_Object.assign), you could just use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) instead of `extend`, or just create your own extend method. Note that the performance difference is likely to be very small.